# Serverless Error: Unable to setup base domain mappings for

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am deploying a Lambda function with Serverless. I did the following:

1. Got my codebase set-up and running locally (using serverless-offline).
2. Deployed my Lambda function to the **dev** stage (`serverless deploy -v`)and tested it there. Since I deployed to dev first, it took the default endpoint of image.example.com/ogImage (where ogImage is my function).
3. Deployed my Lambda function successfully to the **prod** stage. **However** I then discovered that the custom domain was still pointing to the dev stage.
4. Went into the AWS console manually, under API Gateway>Custom domain names>image.example.com, clicked on Configure API mappings, and switched it to use the prod API and prod stage (see screenshot below)

That fixed the problem and now the custom domain (image.example.com/ogImage) is pointing to the prod stage.

**However** when I went to deploy again by running `serverless deploy -v --stage prod`, I get the error:

```
  Error: Error: Unable to setup base domain mappings for image.example.com
      at ServerlessCustomDomain.<anonymous> (/Users/me/software/git/zhxword-image/node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/dist/index.js:164:27)
      at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
      at rejected (/Users/me/software/git/zhxword-image/node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/dist/index.js:6:65)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I am pretty sure that the manual step 4 is what messed it up. How can I reliably set it up so that the **prod** stage is special, and always points to the custom domain, and I can publish repeatedly? I am fine with the whatever approach is standard for other stages - e.g. a path like image.example.com/dev/ogImage, or no custom domain.

Here's the serverless.yml

```
app: zhxw-image                                                            
service: zhxw-image-service                                                
  
plugins:
  - serverless-offline                                                     
  - serverless-domain-manager
    
custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: image.example.com                                          
    basePath: ''                                                           
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}                                          
    createRoute53Record: true                                              
  serverless-offline:                                                      
    host: '0.0.0.0'                                                        
    httpPort: 4000                                                         
    
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x                                                      
  apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:                                                      
      - '*/*'                                                              
      - 'image/png'                                                        
      - 'image/jpeg'                                                       
      - 'image/gif'
      - 'text/html'                                                        
functions:
  ogImage:
    handler: handler.ogImage
    ...
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is because you are trying to used the same domain in two api ... For example for "dev" env I recommend you change, ex: `image-${self:provider.stage}.example.com`. 
 You can't use one domain in two API Gateway.

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamosCarmenates yes that sounds like it could be the issue. Do I have to have a different domain for each stage though? Could I have the serverless.yml file create a single domain, and have the stage be part of the path (e.g. image.example.com/STAGE/...)

Comment: By the way, if the best-practice way of doing this is to have a separate domain for each stage, I will stick with that; I'm still fairly new to serverless.

Comment: I am trying this out, but kind of stuck. In serverless.yml, I added the stage to the domain name: `domainName: image-${self:provider.stage}.example.com`. Then I ran `sls create_domain` to create it. That worked - image-dev.example.com/ogImage is up now. But when I try to create the domain for the prod stage (`sls create_domain --stage prod`) it keeps trying to create the dev stage: "Custom domain image-dev.example.com already exists."

Comment: A little off topic, but if you're only interested in using AWS, and new to this stuff, check out the AWS CDK. I've migrated all my stacks in recent months.

Comment: Thanks @RichardDunn - I'll check it out. Although I'm not an expert, I'm relatively comfortable with AWS itself. This problem is really about how the Serverless framework orchestrates the provisioning of AWS resources. I definitely do want to become more familiar with Serverless itself.

Comment: Definitely do. They both compile / transpile down to CloudFormation on AWS, but with CDK you have all the benefits of a real programming language (IDE linting, typesafety, functions, etc.), no horrible static config files and DSLs. Infrastructure as Code is absolutely the future. Serverless, SAM, etc, are all outdated at this point. The only real benefit to learning Serverless is if you want to target other cloud platforms.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same domain for dev and prod, you can make use of the basePath attribute. Set it to 'dev' when stage=dev and set it to 'prod' when stage=prod

Following serverless.yml should work for you.

```
app: zhxw-image                                                            
service: zhxw-image-service                                                
  
plugins:
  - serverless-offline                                                     
  - serverless-domain-manager
    
custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: image.example.com                                          
    basePath: ${self:provider.stage}  #### Changed here                                                            
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}                                          
    createRoute53Record: true                                              
  serverless-offline:                                                      
    host: '0.0.0.0'                                                        
    httpPort: 4000  
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}   #### Changed here
```

Running the following will create the endpoint image.example.com/dev/...

`serverless deploy -v --stage dev`

And this will create the endpoint image.example.com/prod/...

`serverless deploy -v --stage prod`

Comment: Thank you Sarthak. In your opinion, would you say it's better practice to add the stage to the basePath, like you suggested, or to have a separate domain for each stage (e.g. image-dev.example.com, image-prod.example.com, etc.)?

Comment: I don't think it matters :) Domain name and the path are just to make the URLs more readable/intuitive for the clients. All the actual stuff like Lambda Proxy integrations, API Keys, Usage plans, Monitoring, Alarming etc are all defined at the API Gateway level. So go with the one which you think is more readable for your users/clients :)

Answer (score 0):

ServerlessCustomDomain requires an endpoint to bind to, try adding an event:

> ```
> events:
>   - http:
>       path: /{any+}
>       method: any
> ```